# After upgrading to TFS 2017.3, web portal check ins do not kick off the gated check in build

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2017

We upgraded our TFS to 2017.3 last night, and all appears to be working as expected, except when making changes to files in the web portal.
When I click the Check In button, I get the following error:

```
Your check-in could not be completed because it affects the following gated build definitions. \USA\BuildDefinition To complete your check-in you will need to queue a build of the shelveset Gated_2021-02-05_10.23.14.4571;MyDomain\MyUser.
```

If I make the same change in visual studio, it kicks off the gated check in fine. Just not through the web portal.
Any ideas why that is?

Comment: There is a similar issue have been reported to Microsoft. You can follow it up [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/969311/failed-to-checkin-changes-your-check-in-could-not.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps to re-enable the gated check in.

Navigate to the build pipeline-->Edit-->go to Triggers tab-->Disable Gated check-in -->Save-->Enable Gated check-in-->Save again.

[image]

If above disable and re-enable the gated check-in doesnot work. Please try to re-create the build pipeline and configure the gated check-in.

Comment: Tried disabling and enabling, as well as deleting the CI and creating a new one from scratch. Same error. I also tried editing a different file in source, linked to a different CI, and got the same issue.